# not able to add values to mysql table from node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to insert data into my table, I'm able to do it in node.js when I just put strings in my values.

> var sql = `INSERT INTO teachers (full_name, school, email) VALUES ('alex','bennet','alex@bennet.com)`;

However, when I put the value created by POST method, it gives me a syntax error.

> var sql = `INSERT INTO teachers (full_name, school, email) VALUES (${teacher.name},${teacher.school},${teacher.email})`;

```
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'alex' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO teachers (full_name, school, email) VALUES (alex,bennet,alex@bennet.com) "
```

I dont know why it assumes alex as a column name and not value.

Comment: Put apostrophes around the values, the error shows you that you don't have any. `( '${teacher.name}' ... )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose the string with single quotes to specify as string. So your code should be like this,

```
var sql = INSERT INTO teachers (full_name, school, email) VALUES ('${teacher.name}','${teacher.school}','${teacher.email}');
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: This absolutely should _not_ be the accepted answer, and this should never be used in production, as it is _wide open_ to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes I accept, but here he doesn't worry about that, he don't know why it's error throwing with this syntax, also this is just insert, here we didn't use any where condition

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you are intercalating raw unescaped strings into your insert query, which won't work, since string literals in MySQL need to be escaped by quotes.  The best fix here is to use a prepared statement:

```
let stmt = `INSERT INTO teachers (full_name, school, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`;
let pals = ['alex', 'bennet', 'alex@bennet.com'];

connection.query(stmt, vals, (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```